# How to reduce file size in swf files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, swf

I'm trying to reduce the file size in a swf file that is 17 MB in Ubuntu 14.10. I tried using `swftools` and `avconv`. When I did

```
swfcombine -dz file.swf -o file_new.swf
```

`swftools` only managed to compress to 15 MB and `avconv` loses audio. What can I use to generally make swf files smaller in filesize?